# How to increment variable to count headlines, titles?

Tags: variables, count, jasper-reports

I have a JasperReports template, where I need to count the headlines of different "detail bands".

Now, since the headlines can vary (some datasets can be empty and then the whole band is not rendered), I wanted to use a variable for that.

The build-in variables does not suite, since they don't have a "detail_band_count" or something.

Moreover there is not always a headline in one detail band, there can be 1 or 10 following detail bands, where band 2 - 10 shares the same headline declared in band 1.

However, I managed to create a variable in this manner; but it only counts the pages.

[image: jasper_variable_count]

Is there a possibility to call the Variable Expression on Variable access? So it would always increment, as soon as I write `$V{headline_COUNT}`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with " headlines", columnHeader? or line that you have drawn in a band, furthermore where do you need to use this variable, end of report?

Comment: I need it in my main report. I have subreports if necessary, but my main Report consists of a lot Detail Bands where I use different headlines. With headlines I mean titles. e.g. 1 User Data, 2 User Jobs, 3 User Timeline....., but if the user has no Jobs, it would be 1 User Data, 2 User Timeline .... I want to use the variable on every headline, like a counter of headlines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard for me to see how you can use variables, you would probably need to restructure report, find a grouping strategy, since you need to set `incrementType` to one of the available values and you are correct you can't select "header line" or similar.

However, there is a workaround that you can use to count how many time a specific element is showed using the parameter map `$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}`

**Define** your counting parameter with a default value (avoid it starting as null)

```
<parameter name="countReportElement" class="java.lang.Integer" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

Now on any text field or other element in the band you like to count, you can use a fake `printWhenExpression`, to **increment** this parameter

```
<reportElement x="0" y="262" width="320" height="25" uuid="8fa62997-ffa2-4777-923b-999d372ce09e">
   <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[($P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.put("countReportElement",((Integer)$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("countReportElement"))+1))!=null?true:false]]></printWhenExpression>
</reportElement>
```

Note the ternary operation will always evaluate true (since [Map.put(K key, V value)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put(K,%20V)) will return previous object) and put into the parameter map the value incremented by one every time element is evaluated.

To **display** the value of your count you access the parameter map directly.

```
 <textField>
    <reportElement x="57" y="13" width="100" height="20" uuid="7ca30577-0ca9-47c2-91ae-c7002fbbfbf7"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("countReportElement")]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

be sure to set `evaluationTime` as need in report.

Comment: one more thing: I tried to put this expression in a Variable, that has a shorter name: $P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("countReportElement")
but it happens that he only increment the countReportElement once and never again. Do you know what is happening there? The printWhenExpressions are inserted but obviously they evaluate to false if I put the parametermap in a variable, any ideas?

Comment: Variables have nothing to do with it, forget them, you are basically using the parameter map, however you need to be careful with evalutationTime of your output, hence when is the printWhenExpression evaluated and when is my textField evalutes, also you need to get the value from the map, do not use the parameter directly since this is not reload from the map (jasper-reports uses the initial object in map, it does not expect that you change it)

Comment: thank you very much. Now I got another problem, maybe you know a quick fix: I found out, that I need subheadlines. for example 1.1 User, 1.1.1 User Name, 1.1.2 User Email, ... and so on. But I don't know the depth of the incoming data, so I need to find a generic solution for handling numbering of the headlines. Do you have any idea?

Comment: There is the new report book functionality in jasper reports, but I have not checked it well enough. When I did these kind of stuff I passed a custom datasource  with aggregations (using subreports) to resolve the problem, hence level and numbers could be retrived directly from bean.

Comment: Thanks, ok then I will manage this in my bean. The main level I will handle with the parameter map, then I only need to check the level of the certain element.